# What is this operator? (Three times curve integral)

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis, curves

What is this operator: https://help.libreoffice.org/File:Fo21611.png
I have been seeing it in text-edit documents, but never found any explanation to it. I guess that it is a closed curve integral that has something to do with volume. Can anybody just tell me under which name to research for it.

Comment: It is just a triple integral over a volume, but the circle is there to emphasize that it's a closed volume. I would say, triple integral/volume integral/volume integral over closed volume, or something like that.

Comment: Thanks. So it has nothing (not much) to do with curve integrals. I thought that because of the circle.

Comment: Thanks. So it's not about curve integrals. I thought that because of the circle.

Comment: Well, if you would want to call a surface a "two-dimensional curve" and a volume a "three-dimensional curve", then it is, but yeah, it has nothing to do with a curve in its general known sense. It's just a volume integral (i.e. an integral over a 3-dimensional beastie), and then the circle denotes the fact that this beastie is closed.